# Why does IIS 7.5 recompile the entire website after a reboot?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5

This morning after Windows Updates ran and rebooted a pair of web servers, I noticed that one of the sites running there was not responding. After some digging I noticed 100000s of read/write/delete operations in the asp.net temp files folder. Can we do anything to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tone it down some with precompilation:

[How do I prevent IIS from compiling website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359120/how-do-i-prevent-iis-from-compiling-website)

but IIS thought something changed and needed recompiled.  Were the updates installed hotfixes to framework components perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider deploying your website as a precompiled Web Application instead of a website, if this is appropriate to your situation?